# "Roll over to the next month" or "roll over into the next month"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me if use *to* or *into* in the context below?

> Any unused mobile data will roll over **to**/**into** the next month?

Are both prepositions correct and natural in the context?

Comment: Would you mind terribly saying "idiomatic" instead of natural?

Answer (score 1):

"Roll over *to* the next month" is preferable.

"Roll into" sounds like it has collided with it.